# De onde vem a expressão "que massa"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, origem, girias

No Brasil, em conversas com pessoas mais jovens e/ou nos chats na internet, podemos perceber o uso da expressão “que massa!” ou de suas variações com sentido de ’bom, legal, chique, bonito, elegante’, etc.

Exemplos:

> I) Cara gostei disso, que massa!
>   II) Achei massa sua atitude.
>   III) Sua camisa é massa.

De onde vem a expressão “que massa”? Em Portugal também é utilizada?

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido. Até pensei que fosse redução de *maçada* :)

Comment: Não, é uma gíria até comum por aqui.

Comment: Pois, eu vi que não tinha nada que ver com *maçada* quando li a pergunta toda. Vem na edição portuguesa de 2003 do Houaiss, que é a brasileira de 2001, acho. Diz que é de Minas e Nordeste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A imensa maioria de nossas gírias tem sua origem em determinadas "tribos" e daí, dependendo de vários fatores como por exemplo a televisão, vão ter um maior ou menor grau de penetração na sociedade como um todo. Pesquisei a palavra "massa" e a expressão "muito massa" na web e encontra-se definições com muita facilidade:

> - [bom, legal, agradável, divertido](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/massa) - "aprender línguas é muito massa!"
> - [interessante, muito legal](http://pt.girias.wikia.com/wiki/Massa) - sinônimos:  da hora, irado, maneiro, show, sinistro.
> - [legal, coisa muito legal ou divertida](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/massa/9307/) tambem pode ser usado como "muito massa" que tem o mesmo significado.
> - [gíria que significa algo muito legal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/massa/5918/) - "nossa que carro massa!!!"

Quanto a origem, nada encontrei.  Mas posso dizer que ouvi pela primeira vez em São Paulo, há uns 10 anos. Minha sobrinha paulista usa "muito massa" bem mais frequentemente que meus filhos cariocas e, nas minhas andanças por ultramar, nunca ouvi.  Mas os nossos Tugas do PL podem responder esse item melhor do que eu.

Comment: "Massa" é falado há muito tempo, também não sei a origem, mas é usado no Sul do Brasil.

Comment: Não se usa, por Portugal.

Comment: "nas minhas andanças por ultramar": não sei se é isso que querias dizer, mas isto em Portugal significa África, não significa Europa.

Comment: @ANeves   "nas minhas andanças por ultramar" significa "... andanças além mar" e pode significar qualquer continente.  Minha intenção, no entanto, foi fazer uma referência a Portugal.

Comment: Hmm hmm, sim, estás bem certo, Centaurus. Mas *em Portugal* a palavra "ultramar" quase sempre é uma refência às "Províncias Ultramarinas" ou à "[Guerra do Ultramar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guerra_Colonial_Portuguesa)" - o nome dado pela ditadura portuguesa às ex-colónias portuguesas e à guerra de libertação que por lá houve. (Depois da revolução de 25 de Abril de 74, o nome mudou para Guerra Colonial, e para [ex-]colónias.)

Comment: @ANeves Sim, isso porque já não tinham Goa e nem o Brasil.  E, exceto por Timor Leste e Macao, todas as colônias estavam em solo africano.  Mas se fosse no século 18, o Brasil estaria incluído nas provincias ultramarinas.

Comment: Alguns primos usavam essa expressão em MG há 20 anos, pelo menos.

Comment: MG, SP... Parece ter origem caipira, então: também há mais de 20 anos (beirando os 30, na verdade - inicio dos anos 90) já era usado no interior norte do Paraná.

Answer (score 5):

No ano de 1980, o cantor baiano Raimundo Sodré lançou o álbum “a massa”, título também da [música de trabalho (“Massa”, YouTube)](http://%E2%80%9CMassa%E2%80%9D,%20YouTube). Essa música alcançou grande popularidade no festival da canção, veiculado pela rede Globo, ficando em terceiro lugar. Nessa época, já se podia ouvir pelas ruas de Salvador algo como, “isso é a massa da mandioca”, como forma de elogio. Logo diminuiu-se para, “isso é massa”, e assim permaneceu. Então logo se espalhou pelo resto do Brasil.

Comment: Isso parece muito lógico e é a melhor resposta até agora.

Answer (score 3):

Sou de Recife e na minha adolescência,  nos anos 1980? já se usava muito o termo *massa*...

Era comum se dizer coisas do tipo, “o Show do Barão (Vermelho) foi massa”, “a praia tava massa”, etc.

Vejo hoje que se espalhou pelo Brasil.

Answer (score 3):

Esse uso da palavra *massa* se refere a maconha considerada de boa qualidade, em oposição à “palha”. A expressão ficou popular a partir do carnaval da Bahia, numa música do Caetano Veloso de 1975 chamada [“massa real” (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ctg47lBCjc). Uma das primeiras pessoas a dizer “é massa” no sentido de ’é legal’ foi o próprio Caetano.

Comment: Existem fontes que confirmem essa história?

Answer (score 0):

A expressão *massa* vem da Bahia, não  veio nada de São Paulo nem do Sul: essa expressão é do Nordeste, e ao longo dos anos se espalhou pelo país, e hoje facilmente em vários lugares do Brasil você encontra pessoas falando *massa* pra expressar algo que é muito bom.

Comment: Tens alguma referência para isso que diz?